# Approach to storing forecast time series data using python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, schema

So I want to scrape a weather forecast table once a day and store my results for future analysis. I want to store the data but im not sure how to.

[Example of the data: Forecast Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opHE2.png)

My four variables of interest are wind speed, wind gusts, wave height, and wave period.

This is my first python project involving time series data and I’m fairly new to databases so go easy on me and ELI5 please.

In the Python For Everyone course I recently took, I learned about relational databases and using SQLlite. The main idea here was basically to be efficient in storing data and never storing the same data twice. However none of the examples involved time series data. And so now I’m not sure what the best approach here is.

If I create a table for each variable and lastly one for the date I scraped the forecast. The date of scraping would then serve as the primary key. In this example the variables such as windspeed's first column would be date of scraping followed by the next columns being the forecasted values for the time stamps. Although this would make the storage more efficient as opposed to creating a new table every day, there are a few problems. The timestamps are not uniform (see image, forecast times are only from 3am to 9pm). Also depending on the time of day that the forecast is scraped the date and time values on the timestamps are always changing and thus the next timestamp is not always in 2 hours.

Seeing as each time I scrape the forecast, I get a new table, should I create a new database table each time in sqlite? This seems like a rather rudimentary solution, and I’m sure there are better ways to store the data.

How would you go about this?

Comment: Your question is rather broad and it’s more database related than Python. After re-reading it: you may want to create 2 columns to record the time stamps for scrapping and forecast beside the other data columns for wind and wave. For each scrapping you would produce 30-40 new rows in your database with the same scrapping time stamp and different forecast time stamps. In this case neither of them can be a primary key (neither of them are unique in the database). Either you create an counting number in another column as primary key (or combine both time stamp columns into a primary key).

Comment: With the 2 time stamp columns, it does not matter to the database that the range and maybe the number of forecast values varies from one scrapping to another (e.g. whether there is an hour missing and not recorded). It is rather a question how you want to process and compare your data in the next step. Good luck!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing my comments:

You may want to append forecast data from a new scrapping to the existing data in the same database table.

From each new web-scrapping you will get approx. 40 new records with the same scrapping time stamp but different forecast time stamp.

e.g., this would be the columns of the table using `ID` as primary key with `AUTOINCREMENT`:

| ID | Scrapping_time | Forecast_hours | Wind_speed | Wind_gusts | Wind_direction | Wave | Wave_period | wave_direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Note:
if you use SQLite, you could leave out the `ID` column as SQLite would add such `ROWID` column by default if no other primary key had been specified
(https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)